# execute which command over ssh in python script

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run the command `which solsql` over SSH in a Python script.

I think the problem is in the `ssh` command and not the Python part, but maybe it's both.

I tried

```
subprocess.check_output("ssh root@IP which solsql",
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

but I get an error.

I tried to run the command manually:

```
ssh root@{server_IP}" which solsql"
```

and I get a different output.

On the server I get the real path (`/opt/solidDB/soliddb-6.5/bin/solsql`) 
but over SSH I get this:

```
which: no solsql in
(/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Where is `/opt/solidDB/soliddb-6.5/bin` added to the path? Probably in `.bash_profile` (which is sourced for login shells), not in `.bashrc`, which is sourced for non-login-shells (such as the one started if you start ssh with a command).

Comment: @MihanEntalpo the error is:  
`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ssh root@10.65.163.24 "which solsql"' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: Hey Ortal, if my answer helped and worked could accept the answer so others can see the answer is the right way to go.

Comment: @JackHerer the answers helped me understand the reason to the problem so i chose to go in a different way, your solution seems useful but i didn't try it, i was hoping for something simpler

Comment: @OrtalTurgeman did you find something "simpler"? That is definitely the most simple way from python.

Comment: @OrtalTurgeman, did you find an answer to your question? If any answer solved your question you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, but it is considerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command over SSH, your shell executes a different set of startup files than when you connect interactively to the server.  So the fundamental problem is really that the path where this tool is installed is not in your `PATH` when you connect via `ssh` from a script.

A common but crude workaround is to force the shell to read in the file with the `PATH` definition you want; but of course that basically requires you to know at least where the correct `PATH` is set, so you might as well just figure out where exactly the tool is installed in the first place anyway.

```
ssh server '. .bashrc; type -all solsql'
```

(assuming that the `PATH` is set up in your `.bashrc`; and ignoring for the time being the difference between executing stuff as yourself and as `root`. The dot and space before `.bashrc` are quite significant. Notice also how we use the POSIX command `type` rather than the brittle `which` command which should have died a natural but horrible death decades ago).

If you have a good idea of where the tool might be installed, perhaps instead do

```
subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'root@' + ip, '''
    for path in /opt/solidDB/*/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin; do
         test -x "$path/solsql" || continue
         echo "$path"
         exit 0
     done
     exit 1'''])
```

Notice how we also avoid the (here, useless) `shell=True`. Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: i know the meaning of shell=True, i just don't like when it's false because the syntax gets more complicated and more potential for errors

Comment: Actually it's arguably exactly the other way around. More levels of quoting means more stuff you have to unroll inside your head or just guess. Anyway, the argument to `ssh` is effectively being passed through to a (remote) shell, you're just not making Python run a shell to pass that string to the shell run by `ssh` on the remote host; so the argument of syntactic convenience is moot, if not outright false. (Maybe do read the linked question after all; my answer there expands a bit on this.)

Answer (score 3):

I think what your looking for is something like [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko). An example of how to use the library and issue a command to the remote system.

```
import base64
import paramiko
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(b'AAA...'))
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.get_host_keys().add('ssh.example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect('ssh.example.com', username='THE_USER', password='THE_PASSWORD')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('which solsql')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to debug your error.

Use the code like this:

```
command = "ssh root@IP which solsql"

try:
    retult = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))

print ("Result:", result)
```

It will output error message to you, and you'll know what to do, for example, ssh could have asked for a password, or didn't find your key, or something else.

Comment: Catching the exception so you can reraise it seems rather pointless. The real problem is how to avoid the error, i.e. find out where the command is actually installed.

Comment: I've tried to help questioner to detect the cause of a problem. With this new exception he could see output of command, that he didn't seen before, because of not so detailed exception message (Command 'ssh root@10.65.163.24 "which solsql"' returned non-zero exit status 1). It's better to get the method of solving such problems: debug it the right way, instead of give some one-off solution, and wait while new question arise.

Comment: The [traceback you get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206146/execute-which-command-over-ssh-in-python-script/53207511?noredirect=1#comment93302449_53206146) reveals exactly this information; you are just rephrasing it.

Comment: The traceback DOES NOT reveals exactly this infromation. If you look closer, you'll see, that in my example, e.output is added to the exception text body and it doesn't get outputted in a traceback by default. Try it yourself. Just call subprocess.check_output("ssh noone@nowhere",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT), and tell me, what is the problem with the command except of "returned non-zero exit status"

Comment: But in my example, exception would be: command 'ssh noone@nowhere' return with error (code 255): b'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.\r\nssh: Could not resolve hostname nowhere: Name or service not known\r\n'. See? "Could not resolve hostname ....". It's much more informative, when "returned non-zero exit status" and could be easily solved.